# How to remove navigation bar items when a view controller is removed from navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am removing login view controller from navigation stack once user gets logged in. However, the navigation bar button items added by the login view controller still remains. How to completely remove a view controller from navigation stack?

```
static func removePreviousFromNavigationStack(_ navVC: UINavigationController) {
    var navArr = navVC.viewControllers
    for elem in navArr {
        if elem.isKind(of: LoginViewController.self) {
            if let vc = StateData.loginVC {
                vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil  // is not working as intended
                vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
                vc.navigationItem.title = "Foo"
            }
            //elem.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
    navArr.remove(at: navArr.count - 2)
    navVC.viewControllers = navArr
}
```

---

`Flow: HomeVC -> ApplyVC -> LoginVC -> FormVC`

After logging in to `FormVC`, I call the remove method to remove `LoginVC` from the stack. This removes the VC, but the nav buttons remains. If I set the nav button to nil, the `ApplyVC`'s leftButtonItem, back button, right button item, home button does not show. There is a transparent back button which when clicked, displays the nav bar buttons of `ApplyVC` as if the `LoginVC` got popped out of the view, but without any changes to the current view.

[image: screens]

Comment: I think the issue is with hiding/show custom and default navigation bar. can you please tell me what you have do in applyVc and here what is **StateData**?

Comment: In `LoginViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`, I am setting  `StateData.loginVC = self`. The ApplyVC has navbar items added. In login VC, the same is done. But after removing the login vc from stack, the apply vc navbar items are not displayed properly as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: First, are you sure the code inside `if let vc = StateData.loginVC { ... }` is running? That is, `vc` ***does*** equal `StateData.loginVC`? If so, it's not entirely clear what all you are doing, so try to put together a [mcve] so folks can help you debug this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `LoginVC` at the time of pushing `FormVC` instead of after the `FormVC` is visible.

I’ve created the same `NavigationStack` as yours.

**1.** Added a `rightBarButton` in `HomeVC`

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    var rightBarItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
        return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks, target: nil, action: nil)
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "HomeVC"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem
    }
}

class ApplyVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "ApplyVC"
    }
}
```

**2.** Added a `rightBarItem` in `LoginVC`

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    var rightBarItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
        return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: nil, action: nil)
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "LoginVC"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem
    }

    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
        let formVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FormVC") as! FormVC
        controllers?.removeAll(where: { $0 is LoginVC })
        controllers?.append(formVC)
        if let controllers = controllers {
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I’ve filtered the `LoginVC` and added `FormVC` from `navigationController’s` `viewControllers array`.

```
class FormVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "FormVC"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant solution. I was spending hours trying to figure this out. Any idea why this does not work after pushing `FormVC`, considering that both does the same thing, removing `LoginVC` from the stack?

Comment: This was really helpful. Worked perfectly